# Is spring boot mandatory for running karate tests in parallel?

Tags: karate

How can I run karate tests in parallel without using spring boot framework which is part of karate-demo code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you don't need spring boot framework for running karate test in parallel.

If you are having your own project with your own api/any public api and your own karate tests written for those api you don't need spring boot.

Spring boot is only required if you want to use karate-demo project, as it uses spring boot as sort of mock web service for the tests written on karate-demo.

so if you don't want to have spring boot don't use karate-demo.

**Now how to run your tests in parallel,**

a sample from karate documentation,

```
@Test 
public void testParallel() { 
   KarateStats stats = CucumberRunner.parallel(getClass(), 5, "target/surefire-reports"); 
   assertTrue("scenarios failed", stats.getFailCount() == 0); 
}
```

here number of parallel threads defined as `5`, you can define as your need.

for more details i suggest you read this documentation,

[Running parallel tests using karate](https://github.com/intuit/karate#parallel-execution)